# Arduino Nano nRF24L01 not reading the message

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-nano

Good evening everyone,

at the moment I am trying to work at a Project called Wireless Robot hand. The goal is to use 2 Arduino Nano and 2 nRF24L01 Modules to make them communicate with each other. At first, I'm trying with an example Code to let the two Nanos communicate. So the first one, Transmitter, should send "Test" and the second one, Receiver, should print it. However, communication is working between both but the Receiver won't read the data that the Transmitter sent him.

Here the code for the transmitter:

```
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RF24.h>
RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN Pins

const uint64_t address = 0xE6E6E6E6E6E6;


void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openWritingPipe(address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.stopListening();
}
void loop() 
{
  Serial.println("test");
  const char sendData[] = "Test";
  radio.write(&sendData, sizeof(sendData));
  Serial.println(sendData);
  delay(500);

}
```

And here the one from the Receiver

```
/* Receiver */

#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RF24.h>
RF24 radio(7, 8

); // CE, CSN Pins

const uint64_t address = 0xE6E6E6E6E6E6;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(1,address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.startListening();
}
void loop()
{
  if (radio.available()){
    Serial.println("*");
    char recvData[32] = {0};
    radio.read(&recvData, sizeof(recvData));
    Serial.print(recvData);
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help,

DizzySailor

Comment: try changing  from radio.openReadingPipe(1,address) to radio.openReadingPipe(0,address);

Comment: I changed the pin CE and CSN and now it works but without reading the data...

Comment: how did you confirm that it works and what is working?

Comment: At first it didnt realize that there was any nrf module because the radio.available always send false. After changing the pins, radio.availabale sends true